# SpringBootTest with RANDOM_PORT in Spring Boot 2.1.1 is using 8080 every time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a test class that is running in Spring Boot 2.1.1 and Java 11 and no matter what I do, it runs on port 8080:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = TestClass.Config.class
)
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = TestClass.Config.class
)
@TestPropertySource( properties = "server.port=0" )
public class TestClass
{
    @LocalServerPort
    private String port;

    @Test
    public void testPort() throws Exception
    {
        mockMvc
        .perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get( "/" )
        )
        .andExpect( MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk() );
    }

    @Configuration
    @RestController
    public static class Config
    {
        @Bean
        ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory()
        {
            return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        }

        @GetMapping( "/" )
        public String test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        {
            //This still shows no random port
            System.out.println( request.getLocalPort() );

            return "ok";
        }
    }
}
```

Even when I try this:

```
@Bean
ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory()
{
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    factory.setPort( SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort() );
    return factory;
}
```

which *does* result in the field `port` as having a random port number, MockMvc still uses the default port for my controller.

How can I get it to use a random port?

Comment: When you configure it yourself you are bypassing Spring Boot and hence it has no way of detecting the port. Remove the `@Bean` for the `ServletWebServerFactory` and the `@TestPropertySource( properties = "server.port=0" )` it looks like you are doing to much here. Also why is your `@Configuration` also an `@RestController`?!

Comment: @M.Deinum Removing those (and adding `@EnableAutoConfiguration` - otherwise it fails) results in the same issue

Comment: You shouldn't have a separate configuration file but just point to your spring boot application class.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the port to 0 , it worked for me.

```
@Bean
ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory(0);
}
```

Running the test twice produces 2 different random ports.

1. 63957
2. 64043

Comment: When I use this, and put a break point inside my controller's endpoint method, I get: `request.getLocalPort() => 80`. The field `port` does show a random number, but it's not being used by MockMvc

Comment: Try it with: `mockMvc
            .perform(
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.get( "/" )
            )
            .andExpect( MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk() );`

Comment: You are seeing port 80 because the `request.getLocalPort()` is getting the value from instance `MockHttpServletRequest` which has a constant port value of 80. `public static final int DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT = 80;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You are free to use TestRestTemplate instead of RestAssured and MockBean as required

```
     import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;    
     import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
     import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
     import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
     import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;    
     import io.restassured.RestAssured;

     @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
     public class BookIT_SpringBootTest_WithWebServerAndRestAssured {
        
        @LocalServerPort
        private int port;
      
     
        @Test
        public void myTest() {      
            
            RestAssured
            .given()
                .baseUri("http://localhost/api")
                .port(port)
                .queryParam("id", "1")
            .when()
                .get("/book/get-book-id")
            .then()
                .statusCode(200);
        }
     }
```